# Laravel - Eloquent - How to sum related data and query agaist it?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**I'm looking for help with database queries, not collection solution**

I have the following models:

- `User`
- `Order`
- `Product`

User `hasMany` orders, and orders `belongsToMany` products

I'm in a place where I would need to query users and select all **sold products**, meaning the sum of all products `quantities` that are attached to the orders.

`quantity` value is stored in the `order_product` pivot table.

Table name: `users`, `orders`, `products` & `order_product`

Ideally, I would like to make queries like: `select all users that have sold at least 100 products`, for example.

`DB::raw()` & `selectRaw` is most likely the way to go, I think(?), but I'm not sure about the syntax and how to actually make the query, with and without `where` clause.

Thanks a lot in advance, this has bothered me for a while

**Database Schemas**

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
});

Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->index();
});

Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id')->index();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id')->index();
    $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned()->default(1);
});
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
});
```

**UPDATE**
This far I have come:

```
\App\User::addSelect([
    'sold_products_count' => \App\Order::whereColumn('user_id', 'users.id')
                            ->join('order_product', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_product.order_id')
                            ->select(DB::raw('sum(order_product.quantity) as qty')),
])->where('users.sold_products_count', '>=', 100);
```

HOWEVER, the last statement `where('users.sold_products_count', '>=', 100)` throws error, cuz there's no `sold_products_count` column.

So I think I'm on the right track, but how I can use the new sum column in `where clause`?

Can I use `addSelect`, or do I have to use something else?

Comment: Please share the schema of the tables, and if possible add an example with sample data

Comment: @Aashishgaba I added the database schemas if that makes it easier to give an advice. Thanks!

Comment: @Aashishgaba I have added the latest progress I have made. Can you help me how I can use `addSelect` column value in `where clause`?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved this

Here's the answer:

```
\App\User::addSelect([
    'sold_products_count' => \App\Order::whereColumn('user_id', 'users.id')
                            ->join('order_product', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_product.order_id')
                            ->select(DB::raw('sum(order_product.quantity) as qty')),
])->having('sold_products_count', '>=', 100);
```

The idea is to first count the sum via `addSelect` and then we can query against the value using `having`, neat

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('users')
    ->join('orders', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('order_product', 'orders.id', '=', 'order_product.order_id')
    ->select('users.*', DB::raw('sum(order_product.quantity) as qty'))
    ->having('qty', '>=', 100)
    ->get();
```